# How to disable the onboard Bluetooth but keep the new add on USB Bluetooth enabled

Tags: usb, bluetooth, hardware

I want to disable the onboard bluetooth adaptor but keep the USB bluetooth enabled. In my windows laptop, I can disable hardware directly from devicemanager, but I dont know how to do the same in Ubuntu.

I am very new to Ubuntu and linux. I have just installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my old HP Pavillion G6 laptop. It has a faulty onboard bluetooth adaptor (keeps disconnecting and reconnecting to bluetooth devices and the same used to happened in windows also). I have recently purchased a usb bluetooth adaptor (TPlink) and it works flawlessly. I want to disable the onboard bluetooth adaptor but keep the USB bluetooth enabled. Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to disable onboard Bluetooth

1.Find the VID and PID of the onboard Bluetooth`lsusb`

[Output] `Bus 003 Device 007: ID 0a5c:21e8 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth 4.0`

2.In /etc/udev/rules.d/ location create a file `vim 01-btdisable.rules`

3.Past the line with your respective VID and PID:

`ACTION=="add", ATTR{idVendor}=="0a5c", ATTR{idProduct}=="21e8", RUN="/bin/sh -c 'echo 1 >/sys/\$devpath/remove'"`

4.Save and reboot